# Problema con Apache Tomcat y Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Estoy intentando levantar en el eclipse con el apache tomcat una aplicacion web pero estoy teniendo problemas... levanto el apache desde el eclipse y me entra al localhost:8080 y al /manager, pero cuando entro a localhost:8080/aplicacion me da error 404.

La aplicacion ya estaba hecha y nos la han pasado, nosotros estamos intentando configurarla para levantarla en local y no hay manera..

Os pongo todo lo que tengo.

JDK 1.8
Apache Tomcat 9

Creo el server tomcat 9 y le añado la aplicacion web, supongamos que el proyecto se llama "aplicacion".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, modifico las propiedades del servidor:
* Elijo la opcion de "use tomcat installation" para que me coja la ruta de donde está el tomcat (ahora mismo está en mi escritorio)
* Desde la configuracion del tomcat, me voy a la pestaña "Modules" y cambiamos el web-modules de "aplicacion" a "aplicacion-web" (por seguir un ejemplo), esto es debido a que en el archivo aplicacion.xml, el nombre de la aplicacion es "", por eso en web-modules hay que poner el mismo nombre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, ahora, compilo todo mediante el ANT.build, me compila correctamente y me genera el .WAR en la ruta donde está el workspace, tal que así /workspace/{name_project}/target, aquí está generado el .WAR

Vale, ahora inicio la aplicacion desde el botón verde (play) de tomcat/eclipse para arrancar la app... y aqui es donde tengo problemas.

Me tarda solo 5 segundos y no me cuadra, es como si no pillara el .war... una vez iniciado el tomcat, puedo entrar a localhost:8080 y a localhost:8080/manager. Si entro al manager, veo mi app "desplegada", y si entro a la direccion localhost:8080/aplicacion-web/ es cuando me da el error 404

```
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.21
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 4 2019 20:19:36 UTC
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.21.0
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\opt\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_40-b26
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\wtpwebapps
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\endorsed
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.5].
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1,283] milliseconds
jul 10, 2019 9:48:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:38 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:38 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:38 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [128] milliseconds.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\docs]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\docs] has finished in [611] ms
jul 10, 2019 9:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\examples]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@492521c4')
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\examples] has finished in [1,111] ms
jul 10, 2019 9:48:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\host-manager]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [609] ms
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\manager]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\manager] has finished in [583] ms
jul 10, 2019 9:48:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\ROOT]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = aplicacion3DS Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [556] ms
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
jul 10, 2019 9:48:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [5,222] milliseconds
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como si el tomcat no me cogiera el .WAR... esta es la configuracion del servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que  he visto es que en la propiedad " -Dwtp.deploy" está puesta la carpeta "wtpwebapps" del tomcat y digo quizas está deployando lo que está en esa ruta.. pues he puesto ahí el .war (tanto el .war como el .war descomprimido) y me sigue sin ir.

Otra curiosidad es que si en la carpeta del apache tomcat, en la ruta ../apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps, descomprimo el .war pero con otro nombre (imaginemos aplicacion-web_2), cuando inicio el servidor desde el eclipse, si que coge ese war, ya que tarda 100 segundos en levantar y sale un comentario que pone "INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\aplicacion-web-2]" y aqui si entro al manager del tomcat, si que me aparecen aplicacion-web y aplicacion-web-2, pero ninguna de las 2 entra (error 404 en las 2).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como si el tomcat del eclipse no me cogiera bien el war (ruta mal definida) pero si lo pongo en webapps si me coge ese war..

Indicar que cuando pongo el .war descomprimido en webapps de la carpeta del tomcat y tarda 100 segundos en levantar el server en eclipse, da un error de BBDD ya que la BBDD que tenemos en el .context no funciona, por tanto aunque la BBDD no funcione ¿no debería de entrar a la aplicacion pero no conectar con nada?, no debería dar el error 404 ¿no?

¿alguna idea?, no tiene sentido estar generando el .war y descomprimiendolo a mano en la carpeta del tomcat, ¿no? deberia cogerlo solo el servidor

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿No debería ser `localhost:8080/aplicacion-web` ?

Comment: Hola JDev,

así es como entro a la aplicación; localhost:8080/aplicacion-web pero me salta el error 404, lo puedes ver en la imagen que subí! :)

Gracias!